# Extending the contents of an including template's block

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django's templating language, you can extend the contents of a parent template's block by doing something like:

```
# child.html
{% extends "parent.html" %}
{% block some_block_in_parent %}
  {{ block.super }}
  ... additional content ...
{% endblock %}
```

Is the same possible in a template that does not extend another template but is included by one? Something along the lines of:

```
# including_template.html
{% include "included_template.html" %}

# included_template.html
{% block some_block_in_including_template %}
  {{ block.??? }}
  ... additional content ...
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not process blocks in included files.  This is for simple shared areas of the webpage, if you need to insert dynamic content in a block you will want to use a layout page.